# Laurent Series of $\displaystyle f(z)=(z-3)\cdot\sin\Big({\frac{1}{z+2}}\Big)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I  need to find the Laurent series of $\displaystyle f(z)=(z-3)\cdot\sin\Big({\frac{1}{z+2}}\Big)$ around $z=-2$.

I don't know what to do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Start with Taylor series for $\sin x$, substitute opportunely $x=(z+2)^{-1}$, then consider $z-3=z+2-5$.